# AWS Elastic Beanstalk "Impaired services on all instances."

Tags: java, spring, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring service that I'm trying to load load into AWS Beanstalk. When i create the environment and upload my .war file it just stays stuck on degraded. When i look through the logs for errors i cannot see any errors. Also when try and connect to my url, for example http://something.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/, i get a 502 error. I've already looked at the documentation provided by amazon that states the red degraded message means that all/most of the requests to you page are failing. Any idea how i can find the issue? See the screenshot below for the Enhanced Health Overview.

Comment: Has it ever worked? If you revert to something that did work and upload does it fix it? 502 and degraded could mean anything, bad annotations, server config, database problems, etc etc.

Comment: It runs locally and says deployed under status but that's all I know. Is there a way to see if it failed to deploy? I've checked multiple logs and saw no errors.

Comment: have you looked at the logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it turned out that i was getting an error in my logs but i was not able to see them. I had to ignore all of the eb-something log files. I needed to be looking at the web-1.log. This file may be named different depending on your instance and your environment but this is where i could actually see my error.

Comment: did you fix the issue? i'm having the same issue.

Comment: i finally found out what he means.. anyone finding the logs you need to find this section in your aws EB log file ..

----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.[something].log
----------------------------------------

Answer (score 2):

people who are finding their actual log can look up for this section in their EB log file.

---

### /var/log/web.stdout.log

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, with "Impaired services on all instances."

As suggested above, I ssh'd into the elastic beanstalk instance and looked at /var/log/web.stdout.log.
As I found there, my problem was that I was following a django tutorial and created a django config file with the WSGIPath pointing to the project name that was in the tutorial, but my actual project had a different name.
I corrected the mistake, wiped the elastic beanstalk instance and set up the environment again from scratch.
No problems at all this time, everything turned green immediately.